# How to identify entries with all completed tasks?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have a table Task_status like below:

```
id  TaskId  SubTaskId   status
1   1           1       Complete
2   1           2       Complete
3   1           3       Complete
4   2           4       InProgress
5   2           5       Complete
```

I want to find all the taskId whose all child tasks are Complete. How can I write that query?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code for your query that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having` to check if the number of rows per task equal the number of rows with Complete status.

```
select taskId
from tbl
group by taskId
having count(*) = sum(status='Complete')
```